# Emacs - Company: An error occurred in auto-begin Invalid function

Tags: java, emacs, elisp, intellisense, eclim

I'm working in a fresh configuration of GNU Emacs 24.3.1. I want to use emacs-eclim with company. Company works correctly, but if I open a java file, it stops working correctly, yelling this error message:

```
Company: An error occurred in auto-begin 
Invalid function: (java-mode javascript-mode js-mode ruby-mode php-mode c-mode c++-mode)
```

my Emacs configuration:

```
(require 'iso-transl)
(require 'recentf)
(require 'recentf-ext)
(require 'eclim)
(require 'company-emacs-eclim)
(require 'eclimd)
```

and my hooks:

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook
      (lambda ()
         (iswitchb-mode)
         (helm-mode 1)
         (auto-indent-global-mode)
         (toggle-diredp-find-file-reuse-dir 1)
         (recentf-mode 1)
         (global-flycheck-mode)
         (auto-indent-global-mode)
         (autopair-global-mode)
         (projectile-global-mode)
         (global-pretty-mode)
         (global-eclim-mode)
         (global-company-mode t)
         (yas-global-mode 1)))

(add-hook 'java-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (company-emacs-eclim-setup)
        (help-at-pt-set-timer)
        ))
```

These are the packages I have installed, via the Emacs package manager:

ace-jump-mode, auto-indent-mode, autopair, company, dash, dired+, emacs-eclim, epl, f, flycheck, fringe-helper, helm, helm-company, helm-flycheck, helm-projectile-all, hexrgb, java-snippets, javadoc-lookup, multi-term, multiple-cursors, pkg-info, powerline, pretty-mode, projectile, recentf-ext, s, sublime-themes, visual-regexp, visual-regexp-steroids, and  yasnippet.

Here is the debug information from Emacs:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-function (java-mode javascript-mode js-mode ruby-mode php-mode c-mode c++-mode))
  (java-mode javascript-mode js-mode ruby-mode php-mode c-mode c++-mode)(128)
  eclim-completion-start()
  (let ((start (eclim-completion-start))) (if start (progn (buffer-substring-no-properties start (point)))))
  (cond ((eql command (quote interactive)) (company-begin-backend (quote company-emacs-eclim))) ((eql command (quote prefix)) (let ((start (eclim-completion-start))) (if start (progn (buffer-substring-no-properties start (point)))))) ((eql command (quote candidates)) (company-emacs-eclim--candidates arg)) ((eql command (quote annotation)) (company-emacs-eclim--annotation arg)) ((eql command (quote meta)) (eclim--completion-documentation (concat arg (company-emacs-eclim--annotation arg)))) ((eql command (quote no-cache)) (equal arg "")) ((eql command (quote ignore-case)) t) ((eql command (quote sorted)) t) ((eql command (quote post-completion)) (let ((ann (company-emacs-eclim--annotation arg))) (if ann (progn (insert ann))) (eclim--completion-action))))
  company-emacs-eclim(prefix)
  #[0 "\n\203   [LONG STRING THAT CANNOT BE COPY]
  company--begin-new()
  company-begin()
  #[0 "\300 \207" [company-begin] 1 "\n\n(fn)"]()
  company-auto-begin()
  company-manual-begin()
  company-complete-common()
  call-interactively(company-complete-common record nil)
  command-execute(company-complete-common record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "company-complete-common")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
```

Comment: Do you have a backtrace if you start emacs with `--debug-init`? if yes, add it.

Comment: See Stefan's answer. And then please report the bug to the emacs-eclim project.

Comment: [Done](https://github.com/senny/emacs-eclim/issues/138).

Answer (score 4):

My crystal ball says that you're bumping into a `case` expression without having loaded `cl` beforehand.
If the problem is in a byte-compiled file, you'll have to recompile the file, otherwise adding

```
(require 'cl)
```

somewhere early in your `~/.emacs` file might help.

Comment: Yep, seems like it. Here's the piece of code that's probably the culprit: https://github.com/senny/emacs-eclim/blob/master/eclim-completion.el#L158

Comment: remove the `eclim-completion.elc` file, and then the `(require 'cl)` should work.

Answer (score 3):

`M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, then provoke the error.  That will give you a backtrace showing not just the error message but what expression was being evaluated when the error was raised.

In this case, some function was expecting a function as one of its arguments, and instead of a function it was passed the list you see: `(java-mode javascript-mode js-mode ruby-mode php-mode c-mode c++-mode)`.

Then you can look deeper in the backtrace to see how the function was passed that list argument, and so on.  You can click a function name in the (left side of) the backtrace, to see its Lisp definition.

Comment: Heh, toggling the debug mode causes the error never show again. But code completion does not occur anyway.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a `*Backtrace*` buffer (i.e., that the debugger is not open in some window)? Do you see `[...]` in the mode line, perhaps? If so, go to buffer `*Backtrace*` to see the error backtrace, and use `q` to exit the debugger. If the backtrace shows you which function raised the error then you can use `debug-on-entry` for that function or a function that called it, and then step through its execution to see just what went wrong.